# ref.read(provider).when() does not enter the data section

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have the code below that once the response is obtained it must enter the data section of the mapEither() function, when executing onPressed() it enters the loading section, the response is obtained but it does not enter the data section

This is the onPressed function

```
floatingActionButton: CustomButton(
        onPressed: () {
          ref.read(makePaymentCreditCardProvider).mapEither(
            data: (data) {
              final res = data;
              ref.read(paymentDetailProvider.notifier)
                .setDate(res.value!.operationDate!);

              ref
                .read(routerProvider)
                .go(CreditCardPaymentConfirmationScreen.routeName);
            },
            error: (error) {
              print("show banner error");
              //TODO: mensaje de error
            },
            loading: (loading) {
              print("show loader");
              //TODO: mostrar loader
            },
          );
        },
        text: l10n.confirmPayment,
      ),
```

The `mapEither()` function is an extension that works like `when()` for AsyncValues but simplifies the process when working with fpdart (PD: using the `when()` function the same thing happens)

This is the futureProvider called

```
@riverpod
Future<Result<CreditCardPaymentResponse?>> makePaymentCreditCard(
  MakePaymentCreditCardRef ref,
) async {
  final repository = ref.watch(creditCardRepositoryProvider);

  final response = await repository
    .creditCardPayment(payload: ref.watch(payCreditCardStateProvider));
  
  return response;
}
```

Has anyone gone through the same thing or have a solution? I have tried several things but it doesn't work.

I've tried changing with the normal when() function but it doesn't work, what I hope is that once the response is obtained when calling the repository request, it enters the when section.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `ref.read` doesn't watch the provider, so you'll only get the value of the provider at the time it is read and nothing after. For situations like this where you need to access the contents of a future provider in an async context, you can use `ref.read(provider.future)` to access the underlying future and then work with that using plain Dart:

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  final resultFuture = ref
      .read(makePaymentCreditCardProvider.future)
      .onError((error, stackTrace) {
    setState(() {
      // TODO: show error banner;
    });
    // Placeholder, it wasn't clear exactly what the Result type was in your example code 
    return Err(error);
  });

  setState(() {
    // TODO: display loading state
  });

  final res = await resultFuture;
  if (!context.mounted) {
    // TODO: potentially run cleanup code if the widget unmounted while the request was running
    return;
  }

  ref
      .read(paymentDetailProvider.notifier)
      .setDate(res.value!.operationDate!);

  ref
      .read(routerProvider)
      .go(CreditCardPaymentConfirmationScreen.routeName);
},
```

As an aside: having a provider fire a *write* API call when it is *read* by pulling a parameter from another provider strikes me as a strange way to use Riverpod. I would put such logic inside a service class and then use Riverpod as a service locator to retrieve it.